# Как замутить пользователя как только он зашёл в беседу в aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть небольшой код, в котором бот при вступлении участника даёт ему мут, но, почему-то, бот выдаёт мне ошибку, как это исправить и сделать, что бы он выдавал мут новым участникам? Код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
async def handler_new_member(message):
     bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, can_send_messages=False)
     await message.reply(f'</b>Уважаемый <a href="tg://user?id={message.reply_to_message.from_user.id}">{message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}</a>Вы вступили в беседу "{message.chat.title}" и вам выдан мут, дождитесь администрации...\n⏰ | <b>Срок наказания: Навсегда',  parse_mode='html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: текст ошибки ?...

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_user'

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/message.html#aiogram.types.message.Message.from_id у `message` нет свойства `from_user`  . Есть `from_id`

Comment: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.restrict_chat_member' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: `await` добавьте перед `bot.restrict_chat_member`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо вам!

Comment: оформил в виде ответ) можете принять чтобы вопрос был закрыт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас было 2 ошибки

первая неверное свойства `message`. Для просмотра всех доступнх можно воспользоваться доступных можно воспользоваться [документацией](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/message.html#aiogram.types.message.Message.from_id) .
у message нет свойства `from_user` . Есть `from_id`.

вторая забыли использовать ключевое слово `await`. Т.к. у вас везде асинхронные функции.

P.S.
первая ошибка что я указал не было ошибкой. Просто не нашел в документации aiogram. Вы также можете использовать `message.from_user.id`.

Comment: Бред, у месседжа есть атрибут `from_user` https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/check_user_language.html  ____       
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message

Comment: @oleksandrigo https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/message.html#message где тут видишь такое?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/99yeMvz то что нет в доке не значит что этого нет вовсе.

Comment: @oleksandrigo странно, тогда почему автор получает такую ошибку  `NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_user` ?

Comment: Есть вероятность что он не оттуда импортировал executor. Но скорее всего из-за забытого await

Comment: message.from_user.id существует, я, например, использую его в message.reply(message.from_user.id) и он кидает айди пользователя, правда не знаю почему там не сработало

Comment: @TFader да я уже понял. Ошибка была просто в забытом `await`